# KOTLIN:What should I do with these errors? could it be my gradle implementations are outdated? or is it with the annotation?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, build.gradle

//this is the error that shows after I rebuild

error: cannot find symbol
  @CheckResult
   ^
  symbol:   class CheckResult

### location: class GlideOptions

[error about the annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLcIq.png)

---

[my implementations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sTUE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Glide also needs its annotation processor imported as a dependency. From their readme:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
  kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}
```

And with Kotlin you also need the `kapt` plugin. Add this near the top of the file under the other plugins:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: already added the apply plugin:'kotlin-kapt' before and the implementations too, error still persists